# Understanding the Topology in a Proof about Ergodic/Recurrent Transformations

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

A portion of **Lemma 3.7.2** of Silva's "Invitation to Ergodic Theory" states the following:

> **Lemma.** Let $(X, \mathcal{S}, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space and let $T: X \to X$ be a measure-preserving transformation. Then, the following two statements are equivalent
>
> 1. If $A$ and $B$ are sets of positive measure, then there exists an integer $n > 0$ such that $$T^{-n}(A) \cap B \neq \emptyset.$$
> 2. If $A$ and $B$ are sets of positive measure, then there exists an integer $n > 0$ such that $$\mu(T^{-n}(A) \cap B) > 0.$$

Clearly, only (1) $\implies$ (2) needs to be shown, and the proof is short:

> Let $A, B$ be sets of positive measure. For the sake of contradiction, suppose $\mu(T^{-n}(A) \cap B) =0 $ for all $n$. Let $A_0 = A \backslash \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty T^{-n}(A) \cap B$. Then $\mu(A_0) > 0$ but $T^{-n}(A_0) \cap B = \emptyset$, a contradiction.

I'm having trouble seeing the argument for $$A_0 := A \backslash \bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty T^{-n}(A) \cap B \implies T^{-n}(A_0) \cap B = \emptyset.$$

What exactly is the reasoning for this claim? Any hints, discussion, and solutions are appreciated.

Comment: That was a typo, my apologies. The correct statement should be $T^{-n}(A) \cap B \neq \emptyset$

Comment: it's definitely false. just suppose $B = T^{-1}A$ and is disjoint from $A$ or something. It's hard to me to give a concrete counter-example because the proof is already operating under an impossible hypothesis (i.e. $\mu(T^{-n}A \cap B) = 0$ for all $n$, for sets $A,B$ of positive measure). I'm pretty sure the proof you're presenting is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the proof given by the book but I figured another one.

Consider $B_0=B \cap \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} T^{-n}(A)$, the point in $B$ that eventually reach $A$, and  $B_1=B \backslash \cup_{n=1}^{\infty} T^{-n}(A)$, point in $B$ that never reach $A$.

$B_0$ and $B_1$ are both measurable and their disjoint union is $B$ so $\mu(B)=\mu(B_0)+\mu(B_1)$.

We have $\mu(B_1)=0$ other by $(1)$ we would find $k$ such that $B_1 \cap T^{-k}(A) \ne \emptyset$ which is not.

Now we have $\mu(B_0)=\mu(B)$ and it gives that for at least a $n$ $\mu(B \cap T^{-n}(A))>0$